# Social network on Parse having more than 1000 followers. How to get latest posts for all?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, parse-platform, social-networking

We are building a social network app based on Parse's AnyPic tutorial.

Anypic uses this code to get latest posts from followers:

```
    PFQuery *followingActivitiesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAPActivityClassKey];
    [followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kPAPActivityTypeKey equalTo:kPAPActivityTypeFollow];
    [followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    followingActivitiesQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
    followingActivitiesQuery.limit = 1000;

    PFQuery *autoFollowUsersQuery = [PFUser query];
    [autoFollowUsersQuery whereKey:kPAPUserAutoFollowKey equalTo:@YES];

    PFQuery *photosFromFollowedUsersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey matchesKey:kPAPActivityToUserKey inQuery:followingActivitiesQuery];
    [photosFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKeyExists:kPAPPhotoPictureKey];

    PFQuery *photosFromCurrentUserQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [photosFromCurrentUserQuery whereKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [photosFromCurrentUserQuery whereKeyExists:kPAPPhotoPictureKey];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:photosFromFollowedUsersQuery, photosFromCurrentUserQuery, nil]];
    [query setLimit:30];
    [query includeKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
```

This piece of code as you can see will get only the first 1000 followers and their posts. But we would like to consider the possibility of a user having followed more than 1000 users. What would be the best way to get all of the recent posts from people I follow while staying in Parse's query limititations?

*PS: When I searched google I have came accross a suggestion telling we can store a lastPostedAt variable to the _User object and ordering the query based on this. But even if it is unlikely, there is the possibility of every user I have followed might have recently posted.*

Comment: @Muhammad it is not relevant. But we want to order by createdAt because we don't want users to keep updating their posts to get on top of the timeline. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should make a loop where it automatically skips the already gotten objects. This can be done in the cloudcode of parse.

Look at the example below:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("fetchMenus", function(request, status) {
  var LocationSP, counter, query;
  counter = 0;
  LocationSP = Parse.Object.extend("Location");
  query = new Parse.Query(LocationSP);
  query.doesNotExist("menu");
  query.equalTo("city_lc", "new york");
  return query.each(function(location) {
    if (counter % 100 === 0) {
      status.message(counter + " users processed.");
    }
    return Parse.Cloud.run('getMenu2', {
      alias: location.get("location_id")
    }).then(function(result) {
      counter += 1;
      return Parse.Promise.as("1");
    }, function(error) {
      return Parse.Promise.as("1");
    });
  }).then(function() {
    return status.success("Migration completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    return status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong." + error);
  });
});
```

Taking from this thread
[Parse.com: query.each executes in parrallel, reaches limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191542/parse-com-query-each-executes-in-parrallel-reaches-limit)

Comment: My problem isn't getting a lot of data from a single table. I am joining two queries to get some data from all my followed users. So using your solution will only still help me to get all the posts from my initial 1000 followed users.

Comment: Ah okay.. What i would do then was to make a Parse.Query.each() in the JavaScript SDK (inside a Background Job or Node.js app, for example) to automatically iterate through every single object that matches the query with no limits.

Comment: Can you share an example of what you are suggesting please? I am not very familiar with Parse JS SDK. Thank you

Comment: I am still looking for some alternatives. I will choose the correct answer in a day